# How to SpaceEvenly and Resize two items in a Row?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to `spaceevenly` an `Icon()` and a [`AutoSizeText()`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) in a `Row()`.
When the amount is long as you can see in the attached images it renders as expected, but when the amount is zero or pretty short, the `AutoSizeText()` is being centered, but this causes that the same distance from the edges is no longer maintained. There is an extra distance caused by the centering. I do not know how to fix this.

Edit. If it wasn't clear, I'm referring to the pink shopping bag icon and the amount showed in the "Riepilogo Settimanale" section. If you look at the Restaurant Icon and its amount, you can notice how they are not centered, they are closer to the left edge.

[image: orginal view]

[image]

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      width: size.width * 0.3,
      height: size.height,
      // height: size.height * 0.055,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraint) {
                  return Icon(
                    icona,
                    color: colore,
                    size: constraint.biggest.width * 1,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Center(
              child: AutoSizeText(
                importo,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: colore,
                ),
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to right-align the text, not center them.

To achieve that, consider using a single `Spacer()` in-between the icon and the text. The outside spacing (margin and padding) can be done using `Padding` widget instead.

Comment: At first, i wanted to have a behaviour similar to the space evenly propery of the Row, i wanted the same space between left edge-icon, icon-text, text-right edge. I don't know how to achive that though, because the text change size as soon as it resize, so the spacer should be able to resize accordingly. I decided that was better to just right align the text how you suggested, even if that is not what i wanted, but seems decent

Comment: @iocomxda, oh, if you wanted to have the same space in 3 gaps, you can try to put 3 `Spacer()` widgets for that. But the texts (having different width) will not align with each other on the page (like having `$2666` and `$0`), so right-align is the most common approach.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation! Didn't know right-align was the most common approach.